# How to check if NSDate is in the specific Month?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

I have an array of NSDates and what I am trying to do is check if dates fall in specific month of the year and group them together in another array. I got month and year as NSInteger. It would help me a lot if you guys can help me with the predicate or simple if() statement.

Comment: Why not sort the NSDates array then loop through it, check each date to see which month/year it's in, and put them in a NSDictionary with <"month-year",Array>?

Comment: The canonical way to do it would be to use NSCalendar/NSDateComponents to extract the (numeric) month from each date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below function and make for loop for array.

```
for(NSDate *date in arrDates){

  if([self isDateFalls:date withYourYear:year andYourMonth:month]){
        NSLog(@"YES DATE FALLS IN YEAR AND MONTH");
  } 
  else{
        NSLog(@"NO DATE NOT FALLS IN YEAR AND MONTH");
  }
}

-(BOOL)isDateFalls:(NSDate *)date withYourYear:(NSInteger)year andYourMonth:(NSInteger)month{

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    if(dateComponents.year == year && dateComponents.month == month){

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```